# abernix/meteord docker build fails while trying to build meteor app

Tags: docker, meteor, mup

I am using abernix/meteord Docker image to build a docker image for my meteor app. It has always worked until recently.

The issue is the install script does not seem to install Meteor properly, causing the build script to fail.
"meteor: command not found"

[image]
And for more context. Here is a recording of the build error: [Recorded Session](https://www.loom.com/share/fb9ff355cfc44a31b018fede2ddf5d98)

Comment: Can you post the error message as text, rather than a video? The `--progress=plain ` option can be used with docker to avoid omitting output.

Comment: Thanks @NickODell, I just added the error message to the Question

Comment: I mean the entire thing. Meteor is not installed. The question is, why? The full output would be useful.

Comment: Actually, there was no error from the install step, that's why I don't know what to do.
Here is a screenshot of the output, adding  the progress=plain flag

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ywmX8oGW9als8VTBANMHQa-VXZP3-nw7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Again, please don't post text as images or videos. Add it to the question please.

Comment: They are not updated for newer Meteor versions (yet), I suggest you to use the more updated images from Zodern: https://github.com/zodern/meteor-docker